# Can one start a paragraph with the word "also"?

Tags: paragraphs

Just wanted to ask this for a school thing... Just a little confused, because no other website already has the answer and if you start it with also, wouldn't it sound wrong? If I could get a response as soon as possible, that'd be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**also** can be used to start a sentence and such a sentence could be the first in a paragraph.  [yourdictionary.com](http://sentence.yourdictionary.com/also)

As in:

> Also, as I have said, the bubbles themselves within the ice operate as
>   burning-glasses to melt the ice beneath.

Comment: Yeah, but such sentences normally sound defensive or pissed. As in "Also, as I may have already mentioned and been completely ignored by you morons ..." Something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Fred Jones is the current front-runner for EL&Uer of the month.  Fred is a blah, blah, blah, working in blah, blah, blah.

**Also** in the running for EL&Uer of the month is Bill Little.  Bill is considered big stuff in Littlesburg, Ohio.

Answer (score -2):

It would sound wrong to me to use *also* to introduce the paragraph. The only time I would put *also* at the beginning of a paragraph would be if the *also* introduced a phrase that happened to be at the beginning of the paragraph:

*Also discussed in the same book is the way pigs can be used to find truffles.*